# Which verb form to use

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, verbs-of-perception

Which verb form is correct?

> They saw that lady **broke** it last year

or

> They saw that lady **break** it last year

Comment: You need to learn what verbs of sense perception are: https://www.englishgrammar.org/verbs-perception/

Answer (score 0):

If "they" actually witnessed the act of breaking, then you should use:

> They saw that lady break it last year

This is because "*saw*" puts "them" into the past tense, but "break" is present, so it implies they were actually there at the time.

The second option "*they saw that lady broke it last year*" does not necessarily mean that "they" witnessed the breakage. Because "broke" is in the past tense it could imply that "they" merely became aware of the breakage afterwards.

For example:

> I saw President Trump **went** to Switzerland.

This could mean that you "saw" this retrospectively, perhaps that you read about it in a newspaper. Whereas...

> I saw President Trump **go** to Switzerland.

... would imply that you actually saw him leave.